# Redux call 2 dispatch returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

this is simple redux application for show posts and todos, when i call dispatch action SHOW_POSTS works nice, but SHOW_TODOS return undefined, why ?

```
let initialState = {
      todos : ['buy milk', 'write code'],
      posts : ['weekly news']
    }


    function counter(state = initialState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'SHOW_POSTS':
          return state.posts
          break;
        case 'SHOW_TODOS':
          return state.todos
          break;
        case 'ADD_TODO':
          return {
            todos: [...state, action.payload]
          }
          break;
        default:
          return state
      }
    }    

    let store = createStore(counter)

    store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))

    console.log('show posts:')
    store.dispatch({ type: 'SHOW_POSTS' })

    console.log('show todos:')
    store.dispatch({ type: 'SHOW_TODOS' })
```

Comment: You broke redux!!!!!

Comment: so funny, but im new in redux and not completely understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to return the entire state on your reducers as the return statement will replace the next value of `state`. What you're essentially doing here is replacing your `initialState` with just the `posts`. You can see this by reverting those dispatch calls. You'll see that `posts` will be empty.

Comment: so what im need to do ? just return state ? im need to return only 1 object, for posts is posts for todos is todos

Comment: I mean...yes. The idea of `showing` posts vs todos makes no sense in a reducer as they are meant to change the current state. Maybe what you want is a third key called `currentlyShowing` and your two actions change that value.